# R Google Sheets moving data between

Tags: r, for-loop, google-sheets

I'm working on a survey where answers are reflected on a CSV file. I have 8 questions where the answers are optional: Strongly Agree, Agree, Disagree, and Strongly Disagree.

[Data Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sunqL.png)

These 8 questions are columns in data_process.csv and I want to get the frequency table of each column and paste the sum of the frequencies on the overarching.csv file accordingly to the variable name.

[Overarching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti1YT.png)

On data_process they appear as columns and in overarching.csv they appear as rows.

Any idea of the function?

I'm trying something like this but is not working.

```
for (x in 1:nrow(freq_table)) {
  if (freq_table[x,] %in% colnames(overarching)) {
  
  overarching[,x] <- freq_table[x,]  
    
  }
}
```

Here is the complete data needed. 3 CSV files and one R file.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xpbR1GaOSi8qSOFS7rhfZKuI-jdYuSsq?usp=sharing